# Best way to remove plastic veneer from wood trim

Tags: trim

I have wood molding with plastic, not Thermifoil, covering (simulated untextured wood grain).
I have tried removing it with a heat gun, sanding and denatured alcohol. The heat gun doesn't remove it completely and the finer convolutions are hard to scrape.

Sanding is tedious and same problem with the finer convolutions.

Denatured alcohol only removes the  printed wood grain.

Looking for a fast and easy solution. Either a flexible sanding wheel or chemical to get it to peel off.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to pull it off and put on new molding?

Comment: Yeah, throw in trash, buy new molding seems like the logical solution here.